# mysql : how to submit 2 sets of checkbox in two different column in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I have two sets of div with different checkbox options :

```
<div id="mobile_device" style="display:none;">
<font size="3"><b>Select the accessories :</b></font>
</br></br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mobile[]" value="charger"/>  Charger &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="mobile[]" value="case"/> Case &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="mobile[]" value="headset"/> Headset &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="mobile[]" value="box"/> Box&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <input type="checkbox" name="mobile[]" value="usb"/> USB Cable &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="mobile[]" value="sim"/> SIM<br/>
</div>

div id="desktop_device" style="display:none;">
<font size="3"><b>Select the accessories :</b></font>
</br></br>
<input type="checkbox" name="desktop[]" value="adaptor"/>  Adaptor &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="desktop[]" value="privacy"/> Privacy Screen &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="desktop[]" value="mouse"/> Mouse &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="desktop[]" value="keyboard"/> Keyboard&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input type="checkbox" name="desktop[]" value="connector"/> Desktop Connector <br/><br/>
</div>
```

Now I was trying to submit the set of checkbox values in two columns in my db.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    { 
        // get form data, making sure it is valid
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $serial = $_POST['serial'];
        $imei = $_POST['imei'];
        $mobile = implode(",", $_POST['mobile']);
        $desktop = implode(",", $_POST['desktop']);
        $chargerno = $_POST['chargerno'];
        $connectorno = $_POST['connectorno'];
        $monitor = $_POST['monitor'];
        $monitorno = $_POST['monitorno'];       



            // save the data to the database
            $sql3= "INSERT INTO devices (type, name, serial, imei, mobile, desktop, chargerno, connectorno, monitor, monitorno) VALUES ('$type', '$name', '$serial', '$imei', '$mobile', $desktop, $chargerno, $connectorno, $monitor, $monitorno)";
            mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql3) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            }
```

But i was getting error like Unknown column 'adaptor' in 'field list'.

How can i submit the selected checkbox values from both the div into two different columns.

Comment: you want to store them as string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$desktop` must be passed as a  String, hence:

```
$sql3= "INSERT INTO devices (type, name, serial, imei, mobile, desktop, chargerno, connectorno, monitor, monitorno) VALUES ('$type', '$name', '$serial', '$imei', '$mobile', '$desktop', $chargerno, $connectorno, $monitor, $monitorno)";
```